# Can't find clang/AST/TypeNodes.inc

Tags: clang, llvm

It's been a while since I've used clang/llvm and my clang include files got messed up (some seem to have been deleted). I have been going through replacing the missing ones thanks to the source code here (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/clang/include/clang).

I'm getting an error because the file, clang/AST/TypeNodes.inc  can't be found. I can't find a copy of this file anywhere online to replace it with, if anyone has a copy of it or advise on how to resolve this that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeNodes.inc is generated from clang/Basic/TypeNodes.td during build time.

From clang/AST/CMakeLists.txt:

```
clang_tablegen(TypeNodes.inc -gen-clang-type-nodes                                                                                                                                                          
  SOURCE ../Basic/TypeNodes.td
  TARGET ClangTypeNodes)
```